# Fortran LAPACK dgesv incorrect results when solving for multiple right-hand sides

Tags: fortran, lapack

I'm trying to solve a system of equations using LAPACK's dgesv subroutine in Fortran. I use the system matrix `B`:

```
B(1,:) = [1.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000]
B(2,:) = [0.11111111111111113, 0.66666666666666674, 0.22222222222222221, 0.0000000000000000]
B(3,:) = [0.0000000000000000, 0.22222222222222227, 0.66666666666666674, 0.11111111111111106]
B(4,:) = [0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000, 1.0000000000000000]
```

and multiple rhs's `P`:

```
P(1,:) = [0.0000000000000000, 1.0000000000000000, 2.0000000000000000, 3.0000000000000000]
P(2,:) = [0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000]
P(3,:) = [0.0000000000000000, 1.0000000000000000, 2.0000000000000000, 3.0000000000000000]
```

Then I'm solving the system using `call dgesv(4, 3, B, 4, pivot, P, 4, info)`. The result is this matrix

```
0.0000000000000000        1.0000000000000000        2.8124999130377573        4.8749998218845638
   6.2499996856786456E-002   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000       -2.1249998931307394
 -0.18749999476131071       0.56250000523868871        2.0000000000000000        3.0000000000000000
```

which is incorrect in every row. I also tried to solve the system for only one rhs at once, like that:

```
call dgesv(4, 1, B, 4, pivot, P(1,:), 4, info)
call dgesv(4, 1, B, 4, pivot, P(2,:), 4, info)
call dgesv(4, 1, B, 4, pivot, P(3,:), 4, info)
```

but only the first row (`P(1,:)`) gives the correct solution:

```
0.0000000000000000       0.74999999580904786        2.2499999287538253        3.0000000000000000
   0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000        0.0000000000000000
   0.0000000000000000       0.52941179749874301        2.9117645384763313        3.0000000000000000
```

In fact, I can reorder the dgesv calls and only the first dgesv call produces a correct solution for the system and all following ones are just incorrect (with exception of the zero rhs).
Does anyone know that I am doing incorrectly?

Edit:
The code I'm running

```
program main

    integer :: pivot(4) = 0
    integer :: info = 0
    doubleprecision :: B(4,4)
    doubleprecision :: P(3,4)

    B(1,:) = [1.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000]
    B(2,:) = [0.11111111111111113, 0.66666666666666674, 0.22222222222222221, 0.0000000000000000]
    B(3,:) = [0.0000000000000000, 0.22222222222222227, 0.66666666666666674, 0.11111111111111106]
    B(4,:) = [0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000, 1.0000000000000000]

    P(1,:) = [0.0000000000000000, 1.0000000000000000, 2.0000000000000000, 3.0000000000000000]
    P(2,:) = [0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000, 0.0000000000000000]
    P(3,:) = [0.0000000000000000, 1.0000000000000000, 2.0000000000000000, 3.0000000000000000]


!    call dgesv(4, 1, B, 4, pivot, P(1,:), 4, info)
!    call dgesv(4, 1, B, 4, pivot, P(2,:), 4, info)
!    call dgesv(4, 1, B, 4, pivot, P(3,:), 4, info)
    call dgesv(4, 3, B, 4, pivot, P, 4, info)

end program main
```

Comment: Please show us a **complete, compilable** code which illustrates the problem. As presented we can tell you little - though I suspect at least part of the problem is you don't appreciate that Fortran stores its arrays in column major order, and that `dgesv` overwrites the matrix you call B. At the very, very, very least please show us how you have declared your variables.

Comment: @IanBush Thanks for the feedback, added my code now! Could you explain how or why dgesv overwrites B? And should I create my matrix column wise and transpose my right hand side P? Or what's your point regarding the column major order?

Comment: The doc of `DGESV` clearly states that the the 3rd argument (your matrix B) is updated on output: https://netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d3b/group__double_g_esolve_ga5ee879032a8365897c3ba91e3dc8d512.html

Comment: As @IanBush suspected, you are mistaking how Fortran stores the 2D arrays in memory. `P(:,1)` is contiguous in memory, `P(1,:)` is not. `P` should be declared as `P(4,3)` and you should put your RHS vectors in `P(:,1)`, `P(:,2)`, `P(:,3)`. At least this is how `DGESV` expects you to do.

Comment: @PierU Yeah you are right, the doc clearly states that. So if I want to solve a linear System with multiple dgesv calls, I would have to permute the Matrix B after each call, to get the original matrix back, right?
And regarding the column major order: Is it **always** recommended, to store the values of a matrix using `P(:,1)` instead of `P(1,:)`. So also for the matrix `B`? Or do I just "need" that for the RHS vectors?

Comment: I just meant that the RHS vectors form the columns of the RHS matrix, and that in a Fortran array a column is `P(:,column_number)`. Same about `B`, but you are still free to fill it up row by row if you like `B(1,:) B(2,:)...` (just, for very big matrices, it would be inefficient as it adresses non contiguous elements).

Comment: And yes you have to reset the matrix B for each new call. But I guess that there exists a routine that can use the updated B matrix after `DGESV` (which contains the LU factorization) to solve for new RHS vectors without the need to do the LU factorization again. Just, I don't know which routine...

Comment: @PierU It's `dgetrs`

Comment: @PierU thanks for the help! Storing the rhs in column major order seems to work

Comment: @IanBush dgetrs looks useful. I'll take a look at the function. Thanks!